# node express not getting bootstrap.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, extjs

I have a directory structure:

```
projectName
    | -.sencha/
    | - app/
        | - view
        | - controller
        | - store
    | - saas
    | - server/
        | -server.js
    | - index.html
    | - bootstrap.js
    | - app.js

I would like to start my app and serve index.html with node. So in server/server.js I have:

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, '../') });
})

And this is working fine but after this my localhost throwing an error bootstrap.js is not found.
```

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html manifest="">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">

        <title>serverApp</title>

        <!-- The line below must be kept intact for Sencha Cmd to build your application -->
        <script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body></body>
    </html>
```

So can you tell me how to solve this?
or else Can you provide me a good link of example which is developed in extjs,express,nodejs,mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite your file structure a bit to serve static files:

Add this line to your `server.js` to serve static files from your `public` folder:

```
app.use('/', express.static('public'));
```

And modify your file structure to this:

```
projectName
    | -.sencha/
    | - app/
        | - view
        | - controller
        | - store
    | - saas
    | - server/
        | -server.js
    | - public/
        | - index.html
        | - bootstrap.js
        | - app.js
```

more info: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Awesome suggesting restructuring the app!

Comment: Thanks for reply. After restructuring the app folder i run my server file. It is showing me this error :TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile

Comment: and add the `'/'` to the `app.use` as I did the modification in the answer.

Comment: Can you tell me how to generate public folder in extjs?

Answer (score 1):

I 100% agree with @Adam on this one! Additionally, you should resolve your public folders to absolute paths, its not a must but guidelines so as we don't get punches ... ;)

You should restructure your app as @Adam suggested, plus

Do the following, it will resolve your issue with good guidelines.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();


 app.use(bodyParser.json());
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 app.use(cookieParser());



//This will enable you to access it form '/'
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public', {index: "index.html"}));

// Rest of the stuff
```

Then if you will visit your URL that you set and port, you'll be able to access.

Using `express.static` is recommended way of serving static content.

Hope it helps!